# Finding Solution set for $f(x)/f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x) =$ $\sum_{i=0}^{n} x^i$

Find all the integer solutions to $\cfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$

**Note**: $f'(x)$ represents first order derivative of $f(x)$

Comment: I would appreciate comments by those who downvote. Since downvoting doesn't serve the purpose.

Comment: I gave you a +1 just because I hate who down votes at random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n\ x^i = \frac{x^{1+n} - 1}{x-1}$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\ f(x) = \frac{(n+1) x^n}{x-1}-\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{(x-1)^2}$$

Hence

$$\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = \frac{\frac{x^{1+n} - 1}{x-1}}{\frac{(n+1) x^n}{x-1}-\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{(x-1)^2}}$$

Can you proceed, arranging the terms and so on?

Comment: Thanks, I will take it forward from here.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = \sum_\limits{i=0}^{n} x^i=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$
$$f'(x) = \sum_\limits{i=0}^{n} ix^{i-1} = \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n} ix^{i-1}$$ $$=\sum_\limits{i=0}^{n-1} (i+1)x^i =\sum_\limits{i=0}^{n-1} ix^i+\sum_\limits{i=0}^{n-1}x^i$$ $$=x\sum_\limits{i=0}^{n} ix^{i-1}+\sum_\limits{i=0}^{n}x^i-nx^n-x^n=xf'(x)+f(x)-(n+1)x^n$$
Hence we can write that $$f'(x)=xf'(x)+f(x)-(n+1)x^n \implies (1-x)f'(x)=f(x)-(n+1)x^n$$
So we can say that
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{1-\frac{(n+1)x^n}{f(x)}}{1-x}=\frac{1-\frac{(n+1)x^n}{\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}}}{1-x}=\frac{x^{n+1}-1-(n+1)x^{n+1}+(n+1)x^n}{(1-x)(x^{n+1}-1)}$$ $$\implies \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{(n+1)x^n-1-nx^{n+1}}{(1-x)(x^{n+1}-1)}$$
I hope you can do the rest.

Comment: So basically you say f(x)/f'(x) = 1-x? I don't think I understood that part. That way there will be infinite integer solutions!

Comment: @user3137471 1.> Look at the derivation and tell me what you don't understand. 2.> Why do you think this will give infinite integer solutions? BTW what is your definition of solution?

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I didn't get the part where you derived 1-x from f(x)/(x*f'(x)+f(x)) , I may be missing something.

Comment: @user3137471 I have added to my answer. See if this fits.

Comment: and by infinite solution set, I meant that for any value of x the answer will be integer for f(x)/f'(x)

Comment: @user3137471 Yes, it will, according to that. As much as I know, solution is well associated with "for what value of $x$ an expression becomes zero".

Comment: @Winther Thanks for correcting. I am updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Winther Does it look okay now? Can you confirm?

Comment: Thanks Winther and Schrodinger. Now you have what Fourier has given.

Comment: Since  SchrodingersCat has enough Karma , I changed my accepted answer in favor of Fourier. I hope you guys don't mind it :)

Comment: Winther Nope I am following Fourier's answer only as it is straight forward. I didn't check the revised answer thoroughly.

Comment: @user3137471 Sorry, I misread the equation. He is quoting $f'/f$ in the updated answer not $f/f'$ as he had before so it's my mistake. I'll remove the last comment. This answer is now correct.

Comment: NP, it looked correct to me on first sight but once you raised doubts I had to double check again. I do miss out on subtle things though. Thanks everyone :)